# Will dependency be injected in this scenario?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, dependency-injection, autowired

module_war is dependent on module_A  which is dependent on module_I(contains interfaces)

module_Imp(implementation of module_I interfaces) and module_I both are in the classpath of war module

module_A contains service DepartmentService with below structure where IEmployeeServiceinterface exist in module_I and its implementation i.e. EmployeeServiceImpl
 exists in module_Imp

```
DepartmentService {

@Autowired
IEmployeeService employeeService;
}
```

My question is will EmployeeServiceImpl will be auto-injected into DepartmentService ?

Comment: Your question is not that clear. If your DepartmentService required information about Employee then you need a handle to the EmployeeService. Are you asking should you inject the EmployeeService or should it be auto-injected?

Comment: @MinhKieu Updated the question. See if it helps

Comment: This is a Spring project right? @Autowired is Spring annotation. If you DepartmentService is in Spring scanning package base path then it will look for employeeService first by name and then by type. It will throw an error if Spring could not find the bean to inject.